# How can I create a dates-table inside a query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, recursive-query, sql-server-2017

Say I want to match records in `table_a` that have a `startdate` and an `enddate` to individual days and see if on, for instance March 13, one or more records in `table_a` match. I'd like to solve this by generating a row per day, with the date as the leading column, and any matching data from `table_a` as a `left join`.

I've worked with data warehouses that have `date` dimensions that make this job easy. But unfortunately I need to run this particular query on an OLTP database that doesn't have such a table.

How can I generate a row-per-day table in SQL Server? How can I do this inside my query, without temp tables, functions/procedures etc?

Comment: (1) You don't need to generate all the dates if you only care about one date (which appears to be your question).  (2) You don't even need to generate all the dates if you just want overlaps.  You might consider asking a new question with sample data and desired results.  In the meantime, GMB's answer is better for what you want to do than your answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff (1) I want a list of all dates, with (maybe) matching data from `table_a`. That's what's in the question and both currently existing answers. (2) 'better' is not only subjective, but can also be expressed by using the up-and-down arrows. What precisely are you implying with this point?

Comment: . . It is shorter.  It is more concise.  It generates exactly the dates that are needed.  Seems better to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is a recursive query to generate the date series. Based on your pseudo-code:

```
with dates_table as (
    select <your-start-date> dt
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, dt) from dates_table where dt < <your-end-date>
)
select d.dt, a.<whatever>
from dates_table d
left outer join table_a a on <join / date matching here>
-- where etc etc
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a bit of a hack way to do this. I'll assume two years of dates is sufficient for your `dates` table.

Now, find a table in your database that has at least 800 records (365 x 2 + leap years - headache for multiplying 365 = ~~ 800). The question talks about selecting data from `table_a`, so we'll assume this is `table_b`.  Then, create this Common Table Expression at the top of the query:

```
with dates_table as (
    select top 800  -- or more/less if your timespan isn't ~2years
        [date] = date_add(day, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by <random column>) -1, <your-start-date>)
    from table_b
)

select d.[date]
, a.<whatever>
from dates_table d
left outer join table_a a on <join / date matching here>
-- where etc, etc, etc
```

Some notes:

- This works by just getting the numbers 0 - 799 and adding them to an arbitrary date.
- If you need more or less dates than two years, increase or decrease the number fed into the `top` statement. Ensure that `table_b` has sufficient rows: `select count(*) from table_b`.
- `<random column` can be any column on `table_b`, the ordering doesn't matter. We're only interested in the numbers 1-800 ( -1 for a range of 0-799), but `ROW_NUMBER` requires an `order by` argument.
- `<your-start-date>` has the first date tyou want in the dates table, and is included in the output.
- in the `where` of the joined query, you could filter out any excess days that we overshot by taking 800 rows instead of 730 (+leap) by adding stuff like `year(d.[date]) IN (2020, 2021)`.
- If `table_a` has more than 800 records itself, this could be used as the basis for the `dates_table` instead of some other table too.